# How to pull value from bar chart using Selenium Webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My goal is to verify the values in this bar chart using Selenium.

I have not been able to find the chart-value values using Selenium.  Not sure if I should be using XPath or CssSelector.

There are three bars in the chart, for Frequently, Sometimes, and Never.  Currently the values in the chart are as follows:

Frequently:2

Sometimes:1

Rarely:0

I can see the values and the labels for each bar in the page source, but can't find the elements using Selenium Webdriver in C#.

```
<div class="results-chart">
    <div class="chart-bar-container">
        <div class="chart-bar green" ng-style="{'height': graph.Frequently.patientPercent}" ng-hide="graph.Frequently.patient == 0" style="height: 193.333px;">
        <div class="chart-background"></div>
        <div class="chart-main">
        <div class="chart-value ng-binding">2</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-bar orange ng-hide" ng-style="{'height': graph.Frequently.companionPercent}" ng-hide="graph.Frequently.companion == 0">
        <div class="chart-background"></div>
        <div class="chart-main">
        </div>
        <div class="chart-bar-description">Frequently</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-bar-container">
        <div class="chart-bar green" ng-style="{'height': graph.Sometimes.patientPercent}" ng-hide="graph.Sometimes.patient == 0" style="height: 96.6667px;">
        <div class="chart-background"></div>
        <div class="chart-main">
        <div class="chart-value ng-binding">1</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-bar orange ng-hide" ng-style="{'height': graph.Sometimes.companionPercent}" ng-hide="graph.Sometimes.companion == 0">
        <div class="chart-background"></div>
        <div class="chart-main">
        <div class="chart-value ng-binding">0</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-bar-description">Sometimes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-bar-container">
        <div class="chart-bar green ng-hide" ng-style="{'height': graph.Rarely.patientPercent}" ng-hide="graph.Rarely.patient == 0">
        <div class="chart-background"></div>
        <div class="chart-main">
        <div class="chart-value ng-binding">0</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-bar orange ng-hide" ng-style="{'height': graph.Rarely.companionPercent}" ng-hide="graph.Rarely.companion == 0">
        <div class="chart-background"></div>
        <div class="chart-main">
        </div>
        <div class="chart-bar-description">Rarely</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found a way to find the result but it only works because I know the result will always be less than 10.  I am hoping to learn a better way to do this, this method seems fragile.

```
        public static string CheckFrequently()
        {
            var frequently = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.ClassName("chart-bar-container"));
            string result = frequently[0].Text.Substring(0, 1);
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to change your HTML to include IDs to make things uniquely identifiable e.g:

```
<div id="frequently-container" class="chart-bar-container">
  ...
</div>
```

You could then get the 'frequently' bar element by doing:

```
var element = browser.FindElement(By.Id("frequently-container")).FindElement(By.ClassName("chart-value ng-binding"));
```

Otherise I would find all the elements at once and iterate them.

```
// Find all the bar chart value divs.
var chartValues = browser.FindElements(By.ClassName("chart-value ng-binding"));

foreach(var e in chartValues)
{
   var value = Int32.Parse(e.GetText()); // Get barchart value.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I learned that I should have been looking at the "frequently-containter" class.  I'm testing a website being built for us by a third party and I'm going to pass on your suggestion to include unique identifiers.